# nodejs browser on close

Tags: javascript, node.js

i am trying to find a way to tell if my user has closed his browser / tab.

For this i have my client script:

```
 $( window ).unload(function() {
   socket.emit('browserClose');
});
```

And my server script:

```
    socket.on('browserClose', function()
{
    var id = socket.request.cookie.lb_login_id;
    console.log('this user has closed his broswer: ' + id);
})
```

In the long run i need this to remove the user from an `array` i keep of users

However the function is not being called (as nothing is being consoled to the log)

Comment: If you're using socketio, try with `disconnect` event

Comment: First of all there's a typo: you're sending a 'b**rosw**erClose' event, but expecting a 'b**rows**erClose' event to arrive...

Comment: @doldt i changed this however the console is still not called

Comment: Orion is right. There's a native socket.on('disconnect', function(){...

Comment: @JeremyThille Yeah i know however im not looking for the disconnect event since that happens on every page change

Comment: @MarcRasmussen Well, you can wait for few seconds if new connection is established. No? Then it was not a reload :) Do you really need to know detailed information about the user's behavior? I would say it would be security exploit - for the browser to send further communication, when user requires it being immediately destroyed.

Comment: Socket.io is not designed for pages changes. It is designed to keep a permanent contact between server and client, like for chats and all. If you change your page, it breaks the connection. I believe that's not the right usage for socket.io, is it?

Comment: @JeremyThille You are right however when you want an interactive notification system & chat that can go across pages what would you then recommend i use?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve, but having a navigation by pages AND keeping the same chat open in all pages sounds very difficult to me. You could perhaps try to make a single-page app, keep your chat open, and load your pages via ajax?

Comment: @JeremyThille Yeah that would work however i allready have a pretty large application made in PHP rewriting it would take months

Comment: In that case, I think you can't make the diffference between page change and browser/tab close. All of these will result in a socket disconnection. You'll have to remake a connection and reinit a chat window on each page...